# Angular - Not Finding my Element by ID

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular app I have the code:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
   var meta = document.querySelector('meta[name=description]');

   content = document.querySelector('#theTitle');

   if (content !== null) {
      meta.setAttribute('content', content.textContent.trim());
   }
});
```

In my HTML I have a `h2` tag with id equal `theTitle` however the code `document.querySelector('meta[name=description]')` keeps returning null.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong? I did a `console.log(document)` and its returning everything so the page content appear to be available.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It probably simply doesn't exist when this particular piece of code runs.

Comment: But when i do `console.log(document)` it prints the entire page HTML out and I can see it in there.
So would I need to put a wait for a second or so?

Comment: the console can be deceiving when logging dom nodes and objects. I would scrap the idea and find another way to solve it that doesn't involve getting the content from the DOM directly.

Comment: Is it possible to wait somehow? Like some sort of `isPageLoaded`?

Comment: Yeah a set timeout, but how long you should wait is a crapshoot.

Comment: You could try adding it to the resolve function on the router which will wait until the entire page is rendered to call the action.

Comment: Update - I ended up setting the meta description tag in the controller for one particular page when it loads. Is this acceptable/or can this just extra strain on the controller?